# ASP.NET, Is it possible for forms authentication ticket to timeout in the middle of code behind routine?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

Please consider the code below:

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated == true)
{
    string id = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
}
```

Is it possible for the conditional statement to evaluate true and some background process cause the authentication to timeout before the code inside the block is executed causing it to throw an exception?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authentication is checked at the beginning of the request, before your code is executed.  It will not be re-checked while the current request is executing.